# ffmpeg transparent background with colorkey shows background bleeding

Tags: ffmpeg

I am creating a video with transparent background video with the following command. After creation I want to overlay this video on another video

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=red:s=1920x1080,colorkey=red,format=rgba -loop 1 -t 0.08 -i "CreditWhite.png" -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=1920:-2,setpts=if(eq(N\,0)\,0\,1+1/0.02/TB),fps=60[fg]; [0:v][fg]overlay=y=-'t*h*0.02':eof_action=endall[v]" -map "[v]" -pix_fmt yuva444p10le -vcodec prores_ks credits.mov
```

Creating the video works fine but when I overlay this on another video (using openshot) I get a lot of color bleeding of the background colour around the edges. Any suggestions to improve the ffmpeg prompt to stop this from happening? I tried very slightly increasing the opacity (0.06) as mentioned in another thread without success.
Video uploaded to [youtube for reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xm32LpjNmrA)

UPDATE

Using different colours had the same effect
[image]

Comment: I suppose you're talking about the red edge around texts. See if using different color for `color` would help. There was a recent post here, in which OP was using `blend` filter instead to avoid this kind of problem.

Comment: yes I am reffering to the red edges around text. Tried using other colours with the same result (updated question with example). I assume you are referring for blend option to merge the two videos? This needs to be processed in a 3rd party production software unfortunately. Thanks for your help

Comment: Something just occurred to me... If you're encoding alpha channel (`yuva444p10le`), why losing the transparency in the first place? Just do `ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 0.08 -i "CreditWhite.png" -pix_fmt yuva444p10le -vcodec prores_ks credits.mov` and let downstream software to do the overlaying.